# lua and lsqlite3: speeding up select statement

Tags: database, performance, sqlite, lua

I'm using the lsqlite3 lua wrapper and I'm making queries into a database.  My DB has ~5million rows and the code I'm using to retrieve rows is akin to:

```
db = lsqlite3.open('mydb')
local temp = {}
local sql = "SELECT A,B FROM tab where FOO=BAR ORDER BY A DESC LIMIT N"
for row in db:nrows(sql) do temp[row['key']] = row['col1'] end
```

As you can see I'm trying to get the top `N` rows sorted in descending order by `FOO` (I want to get the top rows and then apply the `LIMIT` not the other way around).  I indexed the column `A` but it doesn't seem to make much of a difference.  How can I make this faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to index the column on which you filter (i.e. with the WHERE clause). THe reason is that ORDER BY comes into play *after* filtering, not the other way around.

So you probably should create an index on FOO.

Can you post your table schema?

**UPDATE**

Also you can increase the [sqlite cache](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_cache_size), e.g.:

```
PRAGMA cache_size=100000
```

You can adjust this depending on the memory available and the size of your database.

**UPDATE 2**

I you want to have a better understanding of how your query is handled by sqlite, you can ask it to provide you with the query plan:

http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html

**UPDATE 3**

I did not understand your context properly with my initial answer. If you are to ORDER BY on some large data set, you probably want to use that index, not the previous one, so you can tell sqlite to not use the index on FOO this way:

```
SELECT a, b FROM foo WHERE +a > 30 ORDER BY b
```

Comment: I can't post it exactly but...
CREATE TABLE dp (p,d,mi,m,d,gc,bd);
CREATE INDEX mi_index ON dp(mi);

the the query would look like "Select p,mi from dp where d=bar orderby mi limit n"

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes so compare with when you index `d`.

Comment: I indexed the column you suggested but I'm still not not getting good performance.  Another thing to consider is that I'm returning about 20%-35% of the rows in this query...I might need to block somehow?

Comment: Actually--it looks like the pragma statement helped some. I'll also look at the site you suggested.  Thank you!..I am still looking for more performance gains though if you (or anyone else) has other suggestions.

Comment: Yes sorry about that I get your point, if the burden is on the ORDER BY, then you need to index `mi` as well.